# Make strings inside trans tag uppercased

Tags: django, django-templates

In my template, sometimes I want to make the translated string passed through `upper` filter. For example, I want to display "Related Links" as "RELATED LINKS". However when I tried, e.g:

```
{% trans "Related links"|upper %}
```

`TemplateSyntaxError` would be thrown. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just use:

```
{% trans "Related links" as rel %}{{ rel|upper }}
```

This saves the translation temporarily in a variable which then can be used to apply filters on it.

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag

Answer (score 2):

Since Django 1.10, you can avoid aliases and just use:

```
{% trans "Related links"|upper %}
```